# Is it possible to use a Chrome Extension to change document.referrer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want my extension to change the `document.referrer` of certain webpages, but searching for this leads to documentation on how to change the `Referrer` in the HTTP request headers.

Is there any way to use an extension to change `document.referrer`, preferably before the javascript(s) of a webpage loads?

Currently I refresh pages where I want the `document.referrer` altered with `window.location.replace(window.location.href)`, but this generates a noticeable flicker, and only can change the referrer to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

override.js:

```
Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'referrer', {
  get() {
    return 'foo';
  },
});
```

This should be put in page context at `document_start`, there are [several methods](/a/9517879).

For ManifestV3 the most reliable method is registerContentScripts: [example](/a/73630593). Specify the correct pattern in `matches` and optionally add `allFrames: true; matchOriginAsFallback: true` if the site uses frames.

Note that due to a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1261964) the sites can extract the original getter and call it on the main document to get the real referrer. The workarounds are mentioned in the report and aren't simple.